# Performance issues with Django

Tags: python, django, performance, profiling

I'm trying to track down some performance issues I have had with Django.  There seems to be a 600-800 ms delay from the time I click refresh to the time the browser gets a response.

I set up a simple view and the profile middleware and this is the view and results:

the view function:

```
def test(request):
    return HttpResponse("It works")
```

The profile results( i used http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/186/):

```
9 function calls in 0.000 CPU seconds

Ordered by: internal time, call count

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/http/__init__.py:487(__init__)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /home/mysite/mysite/mysite/map/views.py:19(test)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/http/__init__.py:532(__setitem__)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/http/__init__.py:517(_convert_to_ascii)
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py:274(__getattr__)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 /usr/lib/python2.6/Cookie.py:573(__init__)
    0    0.000             0.000          profile:0(profiler)


---- By file ----

 tottime
0.0%   0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils/functional.py
0.0%   0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/http/__init__.py
0.0%   0.000 /usr/lib/python2.6/Cookie.py
0.0%   0.000 /home/mysite/mysite/mysite/map/views.py

---- By group ---

  tottime
0.0%   0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/utils
0.0%   0.000 /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Django-1.3.1-py2.6.egg/django/http
0.0%   0.000 /usr/lib/python2.6
0.0%   0.000 /home/mysite/mysite/mysite/map
```

So with that, the profiler isn't returning any numbers, yet Chrome reports a 647 ms delay from requesting the resource to actually getting any response.  My ping time to the server is about 50 ms.  Any ideas how I can get better profiling so I can see where in Django is causing this slowdown?

My WSGI config.  I'm using Cherokee with uwsgi.

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/mysite/mysite/mysite/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)



os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I see this delay(within 20 ms) on different computers as well as different networks.  I'm also seeing it when I just use manage.py runserver.

Comment: How many times did you make a request to get these profiling numbers which are all zeroes?  "Chrome reports a 647 ms delay".  Have you measured how slow your PC is?  Most of slowness of a web site is on the desktop -- not the network.

Comment: What webserver are your using? Did you try using actual profiling tools like apache-utils ?

Comment: I don't know but here is a clue: it is possible that the time was spent **before** your profiler got active.

Comment: Hello, S.Lott - whenever I do a run to that view I get all zeros.  Actual page views return non-zero numbers, but I wanted something very simple.  jpic - That's what I'm thinking, but I'm not sure how to profile it beyond what I've done.  I also tried profiling manage.py runserver, but it didn't give me anything about the actual Django system, it seemed to be just the profile of runserver starting up.

Comment: Please show MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list from your settings

Comment: You can also try measuring load time with another browser or with images and JS turned off.

Comment: And with DEBUG = False in your settings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django might be slowing down due to several reasons. One of the main reason might be inappropriate or no use of [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/). Go through the docs to get the idea about the pros and cons of having a cache. You may also find [this](http://codespatter.com/2009/04/23/how-to-speed-up-your-django-sites/) article useful.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you python interpreter gets reloaded for every request. My guess: The delay happens before the profiling. If you use mod_wsgi, what is your maximum-requests setting? What does your wsgi configuration look like?

Or, you use a lot of JavaScript and the delay is in your browser.

Comment: I'll post my wsgi config in the question.  Currently I'm using uwsgi, but I see almost an identical delay if I use runserver.  There is is a decent amount of JS, but this is the wait to load the page itself.

Comment: The above wsgi config is only python code. I never used cherokee, but there must be some configuration like maximum-requests. You can use milliseconds logging, to see how long cherokee needs for this request: http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_loggers_custom.html

Comment: You can use logging.info('start %s' % time.time()) once at start, if your code, and once at the end of your code. How long is the gap? Django Debug Toolbar has might help, too. But I use it mostly for debugging database intensive views.